# Quadratic equation in Java

Tags: java

So i'm trying to create a function of the quadratic equation in Java, but my I get the error that i should return a double. What am i doing wrong?

```
double quad(double a, double b, double c){
   double x;
   double y;
   x = (-b + Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/(2*a);
   y = (-b - Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/(2*a);
   if(!Double.isNaN(x)&&!Double.isNaN(y)){
     if (x>=y) return x;
     else if (y>=x) return y;
   }
   else if(Double.isNaN(x)&&!Double.isNaN(y)) return y;
   else if(!Double.isNaN(x)&&Double.isNaN(y)) return x;
   else {
     System.out.println("Value is unspecified");
     return null;
   }
 }
```

Comment: `null` is not a valid `double` value, so you cannot use `return null;`

Comment: You should return `Double.NaN` instead.

Comment: Same as for null, using Double.NaN means that you will have to test the result of the method before using it everytime, using an exception give you more freedom as you can decide to catch the exception on every calls independently (try catch everytime) or globally (if one call fails, everything is considered to have failed) or just not catch the exceptions at all and let the program crash (in some cases it could be what you want).

Comment: If x is NaN, y will be NaN too. NaN occurs if any of `a`, `b` or `c` are NaN, or if the discriminant is negative. In any case: it is true for both or neither.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a null.

Null is not allowed in primitive type.

You must use Double, if you want to return "null".

Comment: Even if i replace null with 0.0.. I still get the same error

Comment: That's because you have a path through your code which will not return anything. Add a default return at the end of the method.

Comment: Returning null here is a bad practice, you should not use null to handle errors, or else all the code that will use this will have to handle this special case everytime, while if you use exception you can have your catch anywhere as long the call to the method happens in the try.

Comment: Yes, csmchelvey is right. For that reason, use square brackets is always a good practice, even in a one line if

Answer (score 1):

You can't return `null` from a method whose return type is a primitive type (here `double`). The way you should handle this case here is with exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Without if

```
 else return y;
```

And in the final else just

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("...") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not return `null` as a double.
alternatively you can return -1 or 0, even though your program will use it as a solution.

You may want to throw an exception to show the program that something is wrong.

`throw new IllegalArgumentException("No solution");`

Where you use the function you can say:

```
try {
    double root = quad(a, b, c);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    //No solution
}
```

For more info, you can checkout this [How to solve quadratic equations in java](http://mediocrecode.com/posts/view/solve_quadratic_equations_using_java/)